# Implementing INotifyCollectionChanged with a circular array collection

Tags: c#, arrays, wpf

I have a collection that shows just the last *n* items and it's implemented as a circular array. The problem I'm having with it is how to correctly fire events related to the `INotifyCollectionChanged` interface when adding items.

My add method looks something like this:

```
    public void Add(T item)
    {
        var oldIdx = currIdx;
        currIdx = (currIdx + 1) % _size;   // update the index - looping if required
        var old = internalArray[currIdx];  // this is the old item that will be replaced (it the array is already filled)
        internalArray[currIdx] = item;
        if (count < _size)    // the internal array isn't filled yet...
        {
            count++;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Count"));
            CollectionChanged?.Invoke(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, item));
        }
        else
        {
            CollectionChanged?.Invoke(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
        }
    }
```

This works, but I have to use `NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset` to get the binding to update. I think I *should* be able to use `NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove` or `NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace`, but I just can't figure out how to make it work. If I have something like:

```
CollectionChanged?.Invoke(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove, old)
```

I get an exception thrown because it doesn't have an index. But my collection does not have an indexer, so I really don't know what index it wants. I tried `oldIdx`, `currIdx`, `_size - 1`, and none of them appear to work. It will complain that the item I'm removing isn't at that index.

So how do I make this work? What should be the correct order of steps for removing an item and then adding a new one (or replacing) and when should the events be fired? And what index does it actually want?

Comment: You need with a circular buffer a current insert index and a current remove index.  The buffer may not always be filled and the insert rate and removal rates may not always be the same over short time periods.

Comment: @jdweng: I'm actually not implementing remove at all. I don't need it. I only need something I can keep adding to. So the only time an item is removed is when the array is full. But I think I figured it out - I should be using `0` as the index, because I'm also remove what was the first item added.

Comment: Then you do not have a circular buffer.

Comment: I think you should only send `Replace` instead of `Reset` for event argument when the buffer is filled.

Comment: [Stephen Cleary](http://stackoverflow.com/users/263693/stephen-cleary) has a post regarding [Interpreting NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/07/interpreting-notifycollectionchangedeve.html). According to that, you should use `Replace` with `OldItems` containing `old`, `NewItems` containing `item` and both indexes set to -1.